# Read/write from/to FIFO

Tags: c, linux, ipc, fifo

I've been trying to implement fifo write and read, the scenario is like so, writer1 write 4 bytes to a fifo, reader1 read 2 bytes of them and reader2 read the next 2 bytes, below is what I have done,

writer.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
FILE *file;
unsigned char message[] = {0x66,0x66,0x67,0x67};
file = fopen("fifo1","wb");
fwrite(&message, 1,4,file);
}
```

reader.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
FILE *file;
unsigned char buff[2];
file = fopen("fifo1","rb");
fread(&buff, 1,2,file);

printf("%c\n",buff[0]);printf("%c\n",buff[1]);
}
```

Then I complied both of them and ran reader1 on first terminal and reader2 on the second terminal and writer on the third terminal.

I thought that I would get the first two bytes (ff) in one of the readers and the second two bytes (gg) on the other, but it didn't work as I thought it would, can someone please let me know what I did wrong, please note that I don't care who read the first two bytes or the second two bytes, what matters here is that both readers read2 bytes at a time. I'm using Ubuntu, GCC mkfifo to create the fifo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread` is buffered, so it is reading all four bytes and then giving you the two you ask for.

To get the behavior you seek, use `open` and `read` instead of `fopen` and `fread`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have simplified this example removing this feature but why isn't the reader waiting to insure the file is present? Something like:

```
while (!fopen("fifo1","rb) {
  wait(10);
}
fread...
```

Or at least insuring it is open

```
if (!fopen("fifo1", "rb) {
  printf("error, cannont open file");
}
```

Test each script manually as well. Run a writer. And check and see if the file has what you expect. Put the file there manually and check that the reader is actually finding and reading the file.